# How to call a function from another file in typescript?

Tags: typescript

This question might be dum. I am a beginner for typescript. 
In file A, I want to call a function defined in file B. How do I do this?

Answer (score 23):

Use the appropriate `import` and `export` statements.

Given the following file layout:

```
├── a.ts
└── b.ts
```

**`a.ts`**

```
import {myFn} from 'b';

myFn();
```

**`b.ts`**

```
export function myFn() {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: ... as an extension to the question, based on a configuration file e.g. targetFn='myFn', how would you call targenFn() and have it invoke the named code?

Comment: found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446219/typescript-javascript-call-function-by-string-name

Answer (score 15):

You need to export the function in the file:

```
// File B
export function exampleFunction() {}
```

You can then import it in the other file for use:

```
// File A
import { exampleFunction } from 'path/to/fileb';
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to export the function:

a.ts:

function sum() {}

export sum

Now you just need to import that:

b.ts

import { sum } from "path to file"