# Typescript/Javascript: Call function by string name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `*.ts` file with lots of exported functions like:

```
export function newItemFoo() {
    return {foo: 0, bar: '', baz: true};
}

export function newItemBar() {
    return {foo: 0, bar: ''};
}

export function newItemXXX() {
    return {xxx: 0};
}
```

I want to make a "magic method" (in the same `*.ts`) that can call one of those methods by name, eg:

```
export function magicMethod(name: string) {
    const newEmptyFunc = new Function(`return new${name}()`);
    return newEmptyFunc();
}
magicMethod('ItemFoo');
```

but it raise an error

> Error: newItemFoo is not defined

It works with eval:

```
export function magicMethod(name: string) {
    return eval(`newEmpty${name}()`);
}
magicMethod('ItemFoo');
```

How do I call a function by string name with `new Function()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both using `eval()` and `new Function()` are convoluted ways to achieve the goal.

Try a simpler approach . Create an object that provides a mapping between the values you want to pass to `magicMethod()` and the functions to be called. Then implement `magicMethod()` this way:

```js
function newItemFoo() {
    return {foo: 0, bar: '', baz: true};
}

function newItemBar() {
    return {foo: 0, bar: ''};
}

function newItemXXX() {
    return {xxx: 0};
}

const magicWand: { [K: string]: Function } = {
   Foo: newItemFoo,
   Bar: newItemBar,
   xxx: newItemXXX,   // this allows you to use a different value for the argument
   yyy: newItemXXX,   // ... to use multiple names for the same function
                      // ... and to handle gracefully the calls of non-existing functions 
};

export function magicMethod(name: string) {
  if (magicWand[name]) {
    return magicWand[name]();
  }

  throw new Error(`Method '${name}' is not implemented.`);
}
```

Usage:

```js
magicMethod('Foo')
// { foo: 0, bar: '', baz: true }
magicMethod('Bar')
// { foo: 0, bar: '' }
magicMethod('xxx')
// { xxx: 0 }
magicMethod('yyy')
// { xxx: 0 }
magicMethod('zzz')
// Error: Method 'zzz' is not implemented.
```

However, if you provide such a mechanism to invoke the functions defined by the module you probably don't want to make them public using the standard `export` mechanism but only though `magicMethod()`. It is the only function that needs to be `export`-ed.

Comment: if you want to map methods inside a class, you need to add "this" for example: Foo: this.newItemFoo,

Comment: ... and how could you do it if the functions were in different files?

Comment: @redevill `import` them into the file that defines `magicMethod()`.